# HOW TO SElect line number in TextBox Multiline

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ora-00904, ora-00001

I have large text in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox control in my form (winforms), vs 2008.

I want find a text, and select the line number where I've found that text.

Sample,

I have fat big text, and I find "ERROR en línea", and I want select the line number in textbox multiline.

```
string textoLogDeFuenteSQL = @"SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.2 - Production on Mar Jun 1 14:35:43 2010
```

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

******** MORE TEXT ************

Conectado a:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

```
WHERE LAVECODIGO = 'CO_PREANUL'
```

**ERROR en línea 2:**

> ORA-00904: ""LAVECODIGO"": identificador no v?lido

```
INSERT INTO COM_CODIGOS
```

**ERROR en línea 1:**

> ORA-00001: restricción única (XACO.INX_COM_CODIGOS_PK) violada";

******** MORE TEXT ************

Any sample code about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [TextBoxBase.GetLineFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex.aspx) method. This method retrieves the line number of character position within the textbox.

```
string str = textBox2.Text;

            int index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(str);

            if (index !=-1)
            {                

              int  lineNo = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
            }
```

"This method enables you to determine the line number based on the character index specified in the index parameter of the method. The first line of text in the control returns the value zero. The GetLineFromCharIndex method returns the physical line number where the indexed character is located within the control."

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This only finds the occurrences of the searched text. To compute the line numbers use [Fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93623/fredrik-mork)'s answer.

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 public static void FindErrorInText(string input)
 {
   Regex rgx = new Regex("ERROR en linea \d*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
   if (matches.Count > 0)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
     foreach (Match match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
   }
 }
```